# free command on Debian 7 not showing available column

Tags: linux, memory, debian, debian-wheezy

When I run `free` command on my Debian 7 machine, it doesn't show the last column `available`. The only columns it is showing are:

top, used, free, shared, cache

All the examples I have seen so far show `available` column for e.g. `www.linuxatmyram.com`.

Why is it not showing in my case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's normal, only some versions of `free` support the `available` column.Debian's `free` normally doesn't support `available` but you can look the available memory up by using `cat /proc/meminfo`.